# Invalid argument - Brother scanner not working after upgrade (brscan2 driver)

Tags: 13.10, scanner, mint, brother

**I recently upgraded Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy).**

Scanning via my MFC-420CN had been working in Ubuntu and Linux Mint installs up though Olivia and Oneric.  However once I upgraded from these, scanning broke.  I installed a fresh copy of saucy to verify that it wasn't just something to do with the upgrade.

Brother's website has a notice that all brscan1 models no longer support usb scanning as of Ubuntu 11.10, but it doesn't seem to apply for brscan2 and brscan3 models.  Moreover I found [several](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379213/why-is-my-brother-dcp-7055-not-printing-in-ubuntu-13-10) other [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368375/ubuntu-13-10-printer-brother-dcp-j140w-not-work) that seem to indicate at least brscan4 models are currently working. However I have been unable to verify scanners using brscan2 (or other divers other than brscan4) and ubuntu 13.10 (actually 12.10 and greater) are currently functioning.

For cross-referencing / to help others with the problem the complete list of brscan2 scanners is as follows:

<sub>DCP-110C  DCP-115C    DCP-117C    DCP-120C    DCP-130C    DCP-135C    DCP-150C
DCP-153C    DCP-155C    DCP-310CN   DCP-315CN   DCP-330C    DCP-340CW   DCP-350C
DCP-353C    DCP-357C    DCP-540CN   DCP-560CN   DCP-7010    DCP-7020    DCP-7025
DCP-750CW   DCP-770CW   DCP-8060    DCP-8065DN  MFC-210C    MFC-215C    MFC-230C
MFC-235C    MFC-240C    MFC-260C    MFC-3240C   MFC-3340CN  MFC-3360C   MFC-410CN
MFC-420CN   MFC-425CN   MFC-440CN   MFC-465CN   MFC-5440CN  MFC-5460CN  MFC-5840CN
MFC-5860CN  MFC-620CN   MFC-640CW   MFC-660CN   MFC-665CW   MFC-680CN   MFC-685CW
MFC-7220    MFC-7225N   MFC-7420    MFC-7820N   MFC-820CW   MFC-845CW   MFC-8460N
MFC-8660DN  MFC-8670DN  MFC-885CW   MFC-8860DN  MFC-8870DW  MFC-9420CN</sub>

Similar previously asked questions / problems (but for brscan3 driver hardware):

- [After upgrading to 12.04 the scanner from Brother Printer MFC-290C does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151201/after-upgrading-to-12-04-the-scanner-from-brother-printer-mfc-290c-does-not-work/372474#372474)
- [xsane exits with "Invalid argument" while scanning with Brother DCP-J725DW, what does it mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339621/xsane-exits-with-invalide-argument-while-scanning-with-brother-dcp-j725dw-wha)

---

**So far I've tried:**

- Installing sane-utils
- irections at brother's website regarding the brscan2 install, including using the dpkg -f flag
- editing /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules to include

code:

```
# Brother scanners

ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

- copying files form lib to lib64:

code:

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s ../lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0 .
ln -s ../lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1 .
ln -s ../lib64/libbrcolm2.so .
ln -s ../lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1 .
ln -s ../lib64/libbrscandec2.so .
ln -s ../lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1
cd sane
ln -s ../../lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1.0.7 .
ln -s ../../lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1 .
ln -s ../../lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so .
```

- installing ia32-libs and repeating the sane-utils install
- removing the 64 bit brscan2 driver and replacing it with the 32 bit one, but results of scanimage with the 32 bit driver set-up for usb or network mode were less than promising:

code:

```
# scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

- of the 32 bit windows drivers with WINE eumlating Win2000 or XP -- it almost completes in 2000.

---

**Debugging 64 bit drivers:**

With brscan2 installed I can open up simple-scan and find the scanner; moreover scanimage output indicates that everything is okay:

```
# scanimage -L
device `brother2:bus5;dev2' is a Brother DCP-350C USB scanner
```

But scanning (even as a root user) still doesn't work.

```
> sudo scanimage >image.pnm
scanimage: open of device brother2:bus2;dev4 failed: Invalid argument
```

xsane produces a similar error:

```
 Failed to start scanner: Invalid argument
```

sane-find-scanner produces a pipe error shown here:
http://pastebin.com/tTNMyD1m
but that seems to related to the fact that brother is providing the driver, not sane.

I'm pretty stuck at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just found this link that seems the indicate the results of sane-find-scanner can be ignored, and I should just focus on the invalid argument error: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/brother-mfc-j220-on-slackware-13-37-scanner-cannot-be-detected-help-4175422639/

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/395934/224082). additionaly you can add `brother-lpr-drivers-mfc9420cn` and `brother-cups-wrapper-mfc9420cn`

Comment: @DuminduMahawela aside from the *-dev packages I had all those "scanner drivers" installed.

Comment: I've emailed brother for help, and referenced this question in-case there are any updates.  Brother acknowledged my ticket, but aside from that all I've gotten is dead air.  I bought another printer-scanner based on the [sane compatibility list](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-supported-devices.html).

Comment: The "SOLUTION" section of this page may help?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xsane/+bug/478761

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After I update to 13.10 I got the same error when scanning. There are two problems here.

1. The error **Invalid argument** is not a argument problem, but is a write access problem.
2. The other problem is that the bus and dev number are wrong from the scanimage error.

How to find and fix the problem?

Install the brscan4 drivers from the brother website

```
sudo dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb
```

Check to see if it works

```
sudo brsaneconfig4 -d
```

Test to see if the scanner is installed (scanner need to be powered on). And run as a user NOT root

```
$ scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus5;dev1' is a Brother ADS-2000 USB scanner
$ scanimage --test
scanimage: open of device brother4:bus5;dev1 failed:
Invalid argument
```

or

```
$ scanimage
scanimage: open of device brother4:bus5;dev1 failed:
Invalid argument
```

You can use the following script to update the permissions for the scanner.

```
lsusb | grep -i brother | sed 's/://' | awk '{printf "/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s", $2,$4}' | xargs -i -t sudo chmod 666 "{}"
```

`lsusb` lists usb devices

`grep -i brother` will find the brother device (assumption I made is you have only one brother device connected to the USBs at a time)

`sed 's/://' | awk '{printf "/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s", $2,$4}'` will find the bus & device numbers

`xargs -i -t sudo chmod 666 "{}"` will add write permission to scanner

Here is more detailed information on why we did what we did above

To find out where the brother scanner is on the bus use `lsusb`. This is one of the problems in the scanimage. The bus is 003 and the device is 002 and not bus 5, dev 1 as per scanimage

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f9:60a0 Brother Industries, Ltd**  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
...
```

To fix the problem, you will need to use the path based on the location of the brother scanner in the `lsusb` command. In my case it was `bus 003` and `device 002`. Note that if you unplug the USB cable to the scanner and plug it back in the device, you will get a new number and/or bus. (The number return back to 2 when you reboot the PC)

Examples:

```
sudo cd /dev/bus/usb/003
sudo chmod 666 002
```

or just:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/003/002
```

`Scanimage` need to fix the message when it can not access the scanner to have the right bus and dev number and also tell the user that the problem is a write access problem.

`Brother` needs to update the driver code so that global user can write to the scanner i.e. `chmod 666` to the scanner driver location

Comment: Can anyone confirm this fix? Fortunately, I knocked this scanner off my desk a month after I posted the question and had to purchase a new (SANE compliant) scanner.  Mark / Dan the answer is still a bit unclear due to various grammar issues, please fix them so I can feel comfortable up voting.

Comment: This answer looks really promising as the output from `lsusb` and `scanimage -L` show different dev/bus numbers. I tried changing the permissions on the `/dev/bus/usb/...` file to no avail. Is there another way to get the OS to look at the correct USB bus/dev number for the scanner?

Comment: This worked. After making the changes in the answer and booting up `xsane`, the first time I tried to acquire a preview it would give me a "scanner failed to start" error. But retrying it would work. Now I can scan! :)

Comment: It didn't fixed it for me

Comment: Worked perfectly for me on 15.04 with a Brother DCP L 2540 DW

Comment: marking as solved as it helped at least 2 people.   Wish I still had my scanner to try it with.

Comment: This solution worked for me with Lubuntu 16.04 and Brother DCP-7030. However after reboot all permissions are reset. Looks like a udev rule is needed?

Answer (score 6):

Just add your user to the `lp` group:

```
usermod -a -G lp username
```

After this you will have write permissions for your scanner.

Tested with:

- 14.04 LTS 64 bit up-to-date
- Brother DCP-J315W
- linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 downloaded from Brother Support Center

The permissions for the printer/scanner at `/dev/bus/usb/001` are:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp
```

It's because of this that adding your user to the `lp` group is a solution.

Comment: As indicated by the '#', I was running the command as root and still getting the error, so this was definitely not the solution to the error above.

Comment: Did you copy (or linked with ln -s) the libraries from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib as suggested at http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on#f00101 ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu - please be aware that I'd  normally doc you -1 for this: If you had taken read my question,  particularly what's written under the part "so far I've tried", you'd know the answer is 'yes'.  In the future, please read the entire question before answering.

Comment: Update for this old answer - this is all I needed to do now with Kubuntu 18.04 and a Brother MFC-L3770CDW. I thought I also needed the udev change and the symlinks, but I undid that and it still works, adding myself to the `lp` group solved it all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this program called VueScan, I was searching for mfc-420cn driver and i ran into this website: "http://www.hamrick.com/" I haven't been able to test this though (because I still have yet to find the power cable to my old printer that's been collecting dust.), but it did say it would support a vast variety of printers, so I thought I should post it. Anyways, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but for the price of that software I can buy a SANE compliant scanner!  Since this answer is unverified and only slightly better than "buy a better scanner" I'm going to leave the question open.

Comment: In my (long-ago) experience, VueScan is excellent; probably far superior to most scanner drivers. Its advantages are most apparent for scanning photographs and/or for fine control over the scan quality. I believe you can download and try it for free. The advantage is you never again have to suffer with the limitations of the manufacturer's nasty proprietary driver. Unfortunately you have to pay a third party to continue using the scanner you already paid for. Lots of folks have decided the cost is worthwhile, because VueScan works well on old AND new scanners.

Comment: I've spent several hours trying every fix for this issue (that can be found on the first few pages of Google), and VueScan is the only solution that has worked so far. I wouldn't buy a Brother scanner with Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and according to https://wiki.debianforum.de/Brother_Scanner the "Invalid Argument" error can be caused if the printer is connected to an USB 3 port (controlled by xhci_hcd). It started working for me as soon as I switched to an USB 2 port (controlled by ehci_hcd).

Comment: I had no usb 3 ports on the computer I was getting this error on.

Comment: The same error seems to come up when ANYTHING goes wrong with the libsane-brother2.so.1 library. For example, I installed the brscan2 .deb package without running brother's horrible install script, and I was getting this same error. It turned out that it was because the driver incorrectly looks for libbrcolm2.so.1 in /usr/lib instead where it is, /usr/lib64.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 32bit

I use MFC-7820N and everytime I upgrade the kernel I have to reinstall all the brother drivers.  The ones I have are: brmfc7840nlpr-2.0.2-1.i386, brscan2-0.2.5-1.i386, cupswrapperMFC7840N-2.0.2-1.i386

I then double check that the rule "ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"" has not been modified or deleted in /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules

After all that I reboot.

Lastly, I will give the brother printer it's own USB host controller, just as a extra measure for testing.

Comment: brmfc7840nlpr-2.0.2-1.i386 and upswrapperMFC7840N-2.0.2-1.i386 are printer drivers and irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Might be a 64 bit vs 32 bit thing, however, I never had problems with 64 bit before.  What kernel are you running?  Can anyone else verify that they have this working?

Comment: I also recently upgraded to 13.10 on a 64bit machine. Before my Brother DCP-135C scanner/printer worked, now it doesn't. Also I can't install the old drivers provided by Brother because they conflict with brother-lpr-drivers-extra. If I uninstall brother-lpr-drivers-extra and install the drivers provided by brother, it still doesn't work.