# Brother DCP-J140W does not scan (brscan4, USB connected)

Tags: scanner, brother, sane

My Brother DCP-J140W does print fine (took a week, but nevertheless).  Installing the scanner drivers needed a lot (spread over 6 month) of trial and error,  but worked in the end. I even upgraded from 12.10 to 13.10 to avoid obsolete version-problems.

After invoking either SANE (or XSANE) the scanner seems to be recognized.  (In any case,  if the device is switched off,  SANE reports "no scanner found",  when switched on,  this message does not appear.)  When clicking the "scan"-button,  7 circles start turning, but after a second or two,  SANE reports "scan failed.  Cannot start the scan."  (messages in Dutch,  translated here for your convenience.)  The "change scanner" button shows that indeed the right make and type seem to be found.

Tried to find an answer in the similar questions,  but answers that seem to apply do not make any difference when I try to follow the advise.

Is this a configuring problem, or permissions?  I hope some of you out there can help,  for which I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

My ADS-2000 stopped working upgrading to Debian jessie.  Installing brscan0.4.3 fixed my invalid argument issue.

I entered the site here:
http://support.brother.com/g/b/productsearch.aspx?c=us&lang=en&content=dl

When I searched for brscan4, the top result appears to be out of date with the 0.4.2-4 image (http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you've followed the steps **exactly** as [outlined on
   Brother's
   website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/dlf/000000/006600/dlf006646.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=dcpj140w_all&type2=92&os=128&flang=4&dlid=dlf006646);
   did you use --force-all?  did you test scan using sudo / as root?
2. Ensure you have all of the potentially needed sane related packages
   installed by executing the following and trying to scan as root again aftward:
   `sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils
   libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras
   libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev`
3. If that doesn't work trace though the steps outlined in [my question
   about brscan2
   scanning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389636/invalid-argument-brother-scanner-not-working-after-upgrade-brscan2-driver), but (if you are running in 64 bit mode) ensure you copy over the
   proper files for brscan4 scanners lib to lib64 (there is likely a
   couple differences from what is in my post), if none of that helps
   report back with the outputs of of the following:

   - contents of 40-libsane.rules
   - which, if any library files you needed to copy over
   - the output of `sudo scanimage -L`
   - the output of `sudo xsane`

Comment: Pitty. None of the suggestions help. Sane-utils was installed, the lines in the /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules file are added (system is 32 bit). Sane-find-scanner finds no USB-scanner, akthough sane sees the difference between scanner switched on or off. The question about your brscan2 device does not give me a clue.  What to do next?

Comment: @Nico_P made my expectations a bit more clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and according to https://wiki.debianforum.de/Brother_Scanner the "Invalid Argument" error can be caused if the printer is connected to an USB 3 port (controlled by xhci_hcd). It started working for me as soon as I switched to an USB 2 port (controlled by ehci_hcd).

Comment: Florian, I followed your hyperlink. However, my DCP-J572DW printer/scanner is not that old, and it worked fine in 18.04. After upgrade to 20.04 it prints but does not scan. The response from XSane is "Could not find device 'brother4:bus2;dev1'". Document Scanner finds the correct device name, but when activated it replies "Scan failed. Could not connect to scanner". (Messages in Dutch, translated for your convenience.) Like to hear your opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I have a different scanner now, can't test anything related to Brother anymore... hard to guess from the description alone. Have you tried with sudo?