# Getting Brother DCP-J140W to scan via USB to Kubuntu 14.4

Tags: drivers, scanner, brother

I am running Kubuntu 14.4 and I want to scan with my Brother DCP-J140W, which does not work. I installed

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev
```

as suggested in [Brother DCP-J140W does not scan (brscan4, USB connected)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405412/brother-dcp-j140w-does-not-scan-brscan4-usb-connected)

I went to http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcpj140w_all&os=128 and installed

- Scanner driver 64bit (deb package)
- Scan-key-tool 64bit (deb package)

with `--force-all` and then I ran

```
brscan-skey
```

When I check whether the connection is established I get

```
$ sudo scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus2;dev1' is a Brother DCP-J140W USB scanner
$ brscan-skey -l
DCP-J140W         : brother4:bus2;dev1  : USB                  Active
```

which looks good. When I command `$ xsane` a window opens which says it is searching for devices but then outputs

> Error when opening the device 'brother4:bus2;dev': Unvalid argument

When I go to my scanner and

1. Press "Scanner"
2. Choose scan to image
3. Press "Start"

I get "PC-Connection" on the display but nothing happens. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the main issue was that I need to start `brscan-skey` as the right user. What one needs to do is start it via

```
$ sudo su
# brscan-skey
```

Also I did some mistakes when editing the shell scripts (although this is not directly related to the question). To summarize, the actual command is implemented in `/opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/brscan-skey`. In `/opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/brscan-skey-0.2.4-0.cfg` it is defined which script is started when which option is chosen on the scanner. The respective scripts are in `/opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/script/`, so one needs to edit them if one wants to change settings. A description is mentioned e.g. in https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/Brother/Scankey-Tool/#Scankey-Tool-Optimierung